# Scheduled file sorting with Ruby

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, datetime, file-system, scheduled-tasks

I have a script running as an hourly cron job. It finds all screenshots on the Desktop and moves them to directories sorted by year/month/day.

On MacOS, screenshots are automatically saved to the desktop with the following filename structure:

`"/Users/<USER>/Desktop/Screen Shot 2019-01-02 at 11.56.42 AM.png"`

```
require 'fileutils'

class Screenshot
  attr_reader :filepath

  def initialize(filepath)
    @filepath = filepath
  end

  def dir_exists?
    File.exists?(destination) || FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)
  end

  def date
    @date ||= filepath.match(screenshot_regex)
  end

  def move
    FileUtils.mv(filepath, destination) if dir_exists?
  end

  def base_path
    "/Users/home/Pictures/Screenshots"
  end

  def destination
    "#{base_path}/#{date[:year]}/#{date[:month]}/#{date[:day]}"
  end

  def screenshot_regex
    /Shot (?<year>(.*))-(?<month>(.*))-(?<day>(.*)) at/
  end
end

class Screenshots
  attr_reader :directory
  def initialize(directory)
    @directory = directory
  end

  def filepaths
    Dir.glob("#{directory}/Screen Shot*.png")
  end

  def files
    filepaths.map{|i| Screenshot.new(i)}
  end

  def move_all
    files.each(&:move)
  end
end

Screenshots.new("/Users/home/Desktop").move_all
```

I'm sure there's a less messy approach here and I'd love to hear any criticism.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is over-engineered in a way that makes it hard to decipher.  Because every method is one line long, it's like reading a poem whose lines have been scrambled.  You would be much better off writing a simple function, like this:

```
require 'fileutils'

def move_screenshots(src_dir, dest_tree)
  re = /^Screen Shot (?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2}) at/
  Dir.foreach(src_dir) do |filename|
    if date = re.match(filename)
      dest_dir = "#{dest_tree}/#{date[:year]}/#{date[:month]}/#{date[:day]}"
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(dest_dir)
      FileUtils.mv("#{src_dir}/#{filename}", dest_dir)
    end
  end
end

move_screenshots("/Users/home/Desktop", "/Users/home/Pictures/Screenshots")
```

I wouldn't bother with `Dir#glob`, since it's a bit redundant with the regex.  Note that screenshots aren't necessarily in PNG format: [the image format can be configured using `defaults write com.apple.screencapture type …`](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/07/31/how-to-change-mac-screenshot-file-format/).  I also wouldn't bother testing `File#exists?` before calling `FileUtils#mkdir_p`, since `mkdir_p` implicitly performs that check anyway.

Instead of an hourly cron job, consider creating a [Folder Action Script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html) that is triggered instantly when a file is added to the folder.

Comment: I started off with something similar but broke it apart into those classes mostly for fun, but also with the intent to eventually revisit and expand it to target other common filetypes that might end up on my desktop. Wanted to use these as a starting point for that. Awesome suggestion on the folder action scripts. I had no idea.

Comment: Imagining for a second that this is part of a larger program, would this be an acceptable way to interact with a collection of object x that all need action y performed on them (separate class to represent the collection, mapping the seed data into a group of x instances, then calling y on each from within the collection obj)? Or would I still be overcomplicating it?

Comment: If your program needs to be extensible, or if the classes are polymorphic in more than one method, then OOP might be worthwhile. Otherwise, you are probably overcomplicating it. Post a separate question with a specific use case, if you are unsure.